# Identifying a spider very similar to a brown recluse

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, arachnology

I took this pic tonight when I saw what I thought to be a Loxosceles reclusa or brown recluse. But when I looked closer, the typical pattern on the back of its cephalothorax seems to be upside down! I tried to compare with lots of pics and I was not able to identify this one. Plus, its abdomen is kind of velvet greenish.
Could anyone help identifying this spider please? Last precision : the body size (excluding the legs) is around 1cm.
Thanks Folks!
Photo taken on June the 24th 2018 around 10pm in Toronto, South Ontario, Canada.
PS: Even if one of its leg is fully missing, it was still running very quickly...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think this a nice male Cheiracanthium inclusum, the familiar "yellow sac spider" (outdoors edition).  The abdomen is what you would expect, the very long first pair of legs, the obvious eyes at the front of the head (middle two of the top row).
I'd feel more comfortable if I could see the usual very dark 'face' and chelicerae, but the angle of the photo is such that it might be just hidden.  The carapace pattern looks interesting, but it may well be that the flash of the photo is giving us a different look there.

Here's the link to the Bug Guide page, with a representative photo of a similar male:

https://bugguide.net/node/view/80427

[image]